# JavaScript conditions

Tags: javascript, operators, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong I'd be eternally grateful! I can't seem to get the right combination of parenthesis - how to I combine multiple conditions in one statement?? Obviously I don't expect anyone to modify the code below, I just want to show what I'm trying to achieve.

If someone can explain the logic to me that'd be great

Thanks

```
function ChangeButton()
{
if 
((document.forms[0].IPR.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FNM1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FNM1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].SURN.value == "") && (document.forms[0].GEND.value == "") && (document.forms[0].DOB.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CRIM.value == "") && (document.forms[0].ETHC.value == "") && (document.forms[0].DSBC.value == "") && (document.forms[0].MARK1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].NATC.value == "") && (document.forms[0].COBC.value == "") && (document.forms[0].COD.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FIVE.value == "") && (document.forms[0].PERM.value == "") && (document.forms[0].VISF.value == "") && (document.forms[0].USD.value == "") && (document.forms[0].HAD1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].HAD3.value == "") && (document.forms[0].HTEL.value == "") && (document.forms[0].HAEM.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FEES.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1TIT.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1ORG.value == "")     && (document.forms[0].REF1POS.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1AL1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1AL3.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1AL5.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1EMA.value == "") && (document.forms[0].DISC.value == ""))
&&
((document.forms[0].PERM.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FIVE.value == "N")) 
&&
((document.forms[0].AGNT.value == "") && (document.forms[0].USD.value == "Y")) 
&&
((document.forms[0].CSTRT.value == "") && (document.forms[0].USD.value == "N") && (document.forms[0].CENDD.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CAD1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CAD3.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CAD4.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CAPC.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CTEL.value == ""))
&&
((document.forms[0].AWDB.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FEES.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FEES.value == "Private Funds Self or Family") && (document.forms[0].AWDS.value == ""))
&&
((document.forms[0].RESEARCH.value == "Y") && (document.forms[0].RESSRT.value == "") && (document.forms[0].RESMOA.value == "") && (document.forms[0].RESAR.value == "") && (document.forms[0].RESDIS.value == ""))
{
document.getElementById('submitbutton').className = 'enabled'; 
}
else {
document.getElementById('submitbutton').className = 'disabled'; 
}
}
```

Comment: perhaps some jquery might be in order?

Comment: It is *really* different to tell why some code is "wrong" when we don't know what it is supposed to do.

Comment: what's the question? you have any errors? what you're doing seems OK to me.

Comment: jQuery would be major overkill for something like this. A sensible starting point would be to start by storing `document.forms[0]` in a variable with a short name.

Comment: It's supposed to change the input class based on the conditions in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see

```
...&&...  document.forms[0].FIVE.value == ""
...&&... document.forms[0].FIVE.value == "N"
```

This never be true

EDIT

I think you must change approach, try something like this:

```
function ChangeButton()
{
    var frm = document.forms[0];
    var neverEmpty = ['field1','field2','field3'];
    var mustBe     = {field3:'Y', field4:'N'};

    var status = 'ok';

    for(var i = 0; i<neverEmpty.length; i++) {
        if(frm[neverEmpty[i]] == '') {
        status = 'ko';
        break;
    }
}

for(myField in mustBe) {
    if(frm[myfield] != mustBe[myField]) {
        status = 'ko';
        break;
    }
}
document.getElementById('submitbutton').className = status=='ok'? 'enabled' : 'disabled';
```

}

Comment: Good spot, so I should use || instead?

Comment: it depend... What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

you don't close the brackets

```
if (document.forms[0].IPR.value == "" && document.forms[0].FNM1.value == "" && ect...)
```

it's that simple

Comment: I tried that but Chrome's console kept telling me it was wrong? Thanks for the suggestion, will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more set of parentheses around the whole lot i.e. if (a == b) { .. }

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you don't need **any** parentheses here (except for those that are required by `if` syntax).

```
if(document.forms[0].IPR.value == "" && document.forms[0].FNM1.value == "" &&
   document.forms[0].PERM.value == "" && document.forms[0].FIVE.value == "N" &&
   ...
   ) {
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').className = 'enabled'; 
} else {
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').className = 'disabled'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the input elements that must be non-empty a "class" attribute.  Then find all those elements using that instead of writing that insanely ugly code.

Comment: Thanks that's useful - as you can probably tell, I'm new to JavaScript. Will research your suggested method

Comment: Unfortunately that's a no go, the class attributes are added dynamically via Uniface

Answer (score 0):

You need 1 more paren before and before the first curly brace everything if **(** ... **)** { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code.

```
function ChangeButton()
{
    if 
    ((document.forms[0].IPR.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FNM1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FNM1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].SURN.value == "") && (document.forms[0].GEND.value == "") && (document.forms[0].DOB.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CRIM.value == "") && (document.forms[0].ETHC.value == "") && (document.forms[0].DSBC.value == "") && (document.forms[0].MARK1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].NATC.value == "") && (document.forms[0].COBC.value == "") && (document.forms[0].COD.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FIVE.value == "") && (document.forms[0].PERM.value == "") && (document.forms[0].VISF.value == "") && (document.forms[0].USD.value == "") && (document.forms[0].HAD1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].HAD3.value == "") && (document.forms[0].HTEL.value == "") && (document.forms[0].HAEM.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FEES.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1TIT.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1ORG.value == "")     && (document.forms[0].REF1POS.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1AL1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1AL3.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1AL5.value == "") && (document.forms[0].REF1EMA.value == "") && (document.forms[0].DISC.value == "")
        &&
        ((document.forms[0].PERM.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FIVE.value == "N")) 
        &&
        ((document.forms[0].AGNT.value == "") && (document.forms[0].USD.value == "Y")) 
        &&
        ((document.forms[0].CSTRT.value == "") && (document.forms[0].USD.value == "N") && (document.forms[0].CENDD.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CAD1.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CAD3.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CAD4.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CAPC.value == "") && (document.forms[0].CTEL.value == ""))
        &&
        ((document.forms[0].AWDB.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FEES.value == "") && (document.forms[0].FEES.value == "Private Funds Self or Family") && (document.forms[0].AWDS.value == ""))
        &&
        ((document.forms[0].RESEARCH.value == "Y") && (document.forms[0].RESSRT.value == "") && (document.forms[0].RESMOA.value == "") && (document.forms[0].RESAR.value == "") && (document.forms[0].RESDIS.value == "")))
        {
        document.getElementById('submitbutton').className = 'enabled'; 
        }
    else {
        document.getElementById('submitbutton').className = 'disabled'; 
    }
}
```

USE and IDE, it will make ur life simple.. Cheers to Eclipse IDE :)